# How to pass values in JUnit5 using Spring boot @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: spring-boot, junit5, spring-boot-test

I have this service class @RestClientHeroMovieService in Spring boot which has the @Autowired StatisticsConfig class which is reading properties via @ConfigurationProperties. Now in coverage testing I want to set some test values in StatisticsConfig and test the same ...this is not happening and getting a NPE instead when trying this assert...

Please suggest

**NPE**

```
 Assertions.assertTrue(heroMovie.getHeroName().equalsIgnoreCase("test") && heroMovie.getMovies().get(0).getMovieName().equalsIgnoreCase("TestM") && heroMovie.getSomeTestValue().equalsIgnoreCase(testValue) && heroMovie.getPlatforms().equalsIgnoreCase("WindowsTest"));
```

**Config**

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "statistics")
@Data
public class StatisticsConfig {

    private String platforms;
    private String browsers;
    private String systems;
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class RestClientHeroMovieService {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private RestClientService restClientService;

    @Autowired
    private StatisticsConfig statisticsConfig;

    @Value("${test.value}")
    private String testValue;

    public HeroMovie getHeroMovieDetails(String heroName) throws URISyntaxException {

        String endpoint = "http://localhost:9050/orders/v1/getHeroDetails/"+heroName;

        HeroMovie heroMovie = restTemplate.getForObject(endpoint,HeroMovie.class);

        endpoint = "http://localhost:9050/orders/v1/getMoviesOfHero/"+heroName;
        URI uri = new URI(endpoint);

        List<Movie> listMovie = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Movie>>(){}).getBody();
        heroMovie.setMovies(listMovie);

        heroMovie.setPlatforms(statisticsConfig.getPlatforms());
        heroMovie.setBrowsers(statisticsConfig.getBrowsers());
        heroMovie.setSystems(statisticsConfig.getSystems());

        heroMovie.setSomeTestValue(testValue);

        restClientService.clearAllCache();

        return heroMovie;

    }
}
```

**Test**

```
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})
@SpringBootTest(classes = {RestClientHeroMovieServiceTest.class, MockitoExtension.class})
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = {StatisticsConfig.class})
@TestPropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
public class RestClientHeroMovieServiceTest {

    private final String testValue = "aaa";

    @InjectMocks
    @Spy
    private RestClientHeroMovieService restClientHeroMovieService;

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Mock
    private RestClientService restClientService;

    @Mock
    private StatisticsConfig statisticsConfig;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(restClientHeroMovieService, "testValue", testValue);
    }

    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    public void testGetHeroMovieDetails() {

        HeroMovie heroMovie = getHeroMovie();

        Mockito.doReturn(heroMovie)
                .when(restTemplate)
                .getForObject(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any());

        List<Movie> listMovie = getListMovie();
        ResponseEntity<List<Movie>> responseEntityListMovie = ResponseEntity.ok(listMovie);

        Mockito.doReturn(responseEntityListMovie)
                .when(restTemplate)
                .exchange(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(ParameterizedTypeReference.class));

        Mockito.doNothing()
                .when(restClientService)
                .clearAllCache();

        restClientHeroMovieService.getHeroMovieDetails("heroName");

        Assertions.assertTrue(heroMovie.getHeroName().equalsIgnoreCase("test") && heroMovie.getMovies().get(0).getMovieName().equalsIgnoreCase("TestM") && heroMovie.getSomeTestValue().equalsIgnoreCase(testValue));

    }

    private List<Movie> getListMovie() {
        List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
        Movie movie = new Movie();
        movie.setMovieName("TestM");
        movieList.add(movie);
        return movieList;
    }

    private HeroMovie getHeroMovie() {

        HeroMovie heroMovie = new HeroMovie();
        heroMovie.setHeroId(1);
        heroMovie.setHeroName("test");
        return heroMovie;
    }


}
```

**test.properties**

```
statistics.platforms=WindowsTest
statistics.browsers=ChromeTest
statistics.systems=MicroServicesTest

test.value = testing
```

Comment: can you try adding StatisticsConfig.class to @SpringBootTest(classes = {...}) ? Just to make sure your class is picked up when staring the conetxt

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.. but that also did not help ...statisticsConfig in the service is still coming as null